# ASP.NET/C# display output in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, process, io

I'm trying to start a process ("cmd.exe") and then launching another programs (from cmd.exe) and being able to get the output or send inputs in a textbox.

So i created a new Thread to not freeze the UI and then read the standard output and display it in the textbox.
But it seems that as soon as the process start, the link between my UI and the process is broken.

Here is my code :

```
public partial class exec2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public delegate void Worker();
    private static Thread worker;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void setTextBox(string s)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + s;
    }

    protected void RunEXE()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();     
        psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false; 
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.StartInfo = psi;

        setTextBox("Setting the process\n");

        // Start the process
        proc.Start();
        setTextBox("Process started\n");

        // Attach the output for reading
        System.IO.StreamReader sOut = proc.StandardOutput;

        // Attach the in for writing
        System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = proc.StandardInput;

        // Exit CMD.EXE
        sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");

        // Close the process
        proc.Close();
        setTextBox("Process closed");

        string results = "";
        while (!sOut.EndOfStream)
        {
            results = results + sOut.ReadLine().Trim() + "\n";
            setTextBox(results.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\n"));

        }

        // Close the io Streams;
        sIn.Close();
        sOut.Close();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Init(Work);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setTextBox("TEST\n");
    }

    public static void Init(Worker work)
    {
        worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(work));
        worker.Start();
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        RunEXE();
    }
}
```

But only "setting the process" is displayed.
I think there is something I don't understand in the UI / process managment.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a worker thread and a process on the server; the UI render pipe doesn't sit there and wait for them - why would it? (your code just does `new Thread(...).Start()`). Frankly, you're lucky that you even see "Setting the process" - I would **not** expect that to keep working in the general case. An http response is disconnected; you won't see updates as other things happen. If you want to update a UI that has been sent to the client, you will need something like polling (ajax) or web-sockets.

Comment: Well i'm not used to web application, would you mind to explain how you would do it ?

Comment: @Raizyl I already did - see the last line. That is not a topic that fits into a small post.